# "off and on" vs "from time to time"

Tags: idioms

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms **'off and on'** and **'from time to time'**? The definitions in the Cambridge Dictionary are:

- off and on: happening or existing only some of the time
- from time to time: sometimes, but not regularly

Comment: Idiomatically, we're much more likely to say sporadic events happen [***on and off*** rather than ***off and on***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=happens+on+and+off%2Chappens+off+and+on&year_start=1918&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom "off-and-on" (or on-and-off) is adjectival, in the sense it may be used attributively or as a complement

> Her on-and-off boyfriend...

> Their relationship was off-and-on that year.

But "from time to time" is a prepositional phrase.

> He plays tennis from time to time.

Because one is an adjective, and the other is a PP, one can't be substituted by the other.

The meaning is also different. If someone "plays football on-and-off" it means that there are periods when they don't play football at all, and other periods when they do

```
        on                  off                    on
.   .  .    .   . ..                       .. .      .   ..
```

But if they play football from time to time, it means irregularly, and not often

```
time              time      time      time               time 
.                 .           .       .                  .
```